# X axis labels with extra decimal...increase step to 1

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, linechart

i need help with line chart….i am providing h axis label as 15,16,17,18 but on the graph plotted i also get 15.5, 16.5….how to remove it??? i also used max: 4 in hAxis…still same issue....I also tried tickInterval: 1 but then graph is showing nothing .

```
<script>

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        var val = {{valuess | tojson}}
        var tags = {{labelss | tojson}}
        var week_ranges = {{week_range  | tojson}}

   console.log(week_ranges)
function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    data.addColumn('number', tags[i]);
  }

  data.addRows(val);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Incoming Tag Trends For  Resolver Group :  {{rg}}',
      subtitle: 'Year - {{year}}   Start Week - {{sweek}}   End Week - {{eweek}}'

    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    hAxis : {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 1,
        max: week_ranges.length
      },
      ticks: week_ranges
    }
  };


  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));


  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `format` config option to specify the number format of the ticks...

```
hAxis : {
  viewWindow: {
    min: 1,
    max: week_ranges.length
  },
  ticks: week_ranges,
  format: '#,##0'
}
```

Comment: by using it 1 is repeating two times...like 1.5 is also formatted to 1 and 1 is also 1 so two 1 r shown i guess

Comment: you would need to remove the numbers causing duplicates from the ticks option -- `week_ranges`